# Is Smart Contract of any ERC20 token is always available publicly

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens, erc-20, contract-deployment

Is Smart Contract of any ERC20 token is always available publicly.

If not complete, then what things are generally available,(for eg, except some sensitive information)

And, if not any of them are available, how one gets to know about the functions included inside the token contract, and attackers are able to attack them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EVM bytecode (compiled form) is available/observable to all users at all times.

The data in contract states, including variables explicitly marked `private`, is available/observable to all users at all times. `private` describes visibility to other contracts but it is a misunderstanding to assume it implies protection for confidential information.

`bytecode` is close to the metal and challenging to interpret from a human perspective. Most contract authors publish the *source code* publicly, so humans can see what the contract does. The code is commonly published on Etherscan's website. They compile the submitted source code and compare to the live `bytecode`. If it matches, then the contract address receives the "verified" stamp and they host a copy of the source code. This is optional and outside the scope of the actual EVM.

Hope it helps.